# Silex redirect from Twig template

Tags: php, symfony, redirect, twig, silex

First, I know this is a horrible thing to do and should be done in controller logic only, but what I'm trying to do is create a custom redirect tag in Twig that fires a Silex redirect.

I have a custom node that outputs the following into the doDisplay template:

```
return $this->getEnvironment()->getExtension('silex')->getApp()->redirect('/', 301);
```

Basically this gets the Twig environment and the extension I created which has a getApp method which returns the Silex $app variable, which contains the redirect method.

But this only returns Array() to the screen. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think that you must call to: $this['kernel']->terminate($request, $response);

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking to do is impossible. You can't send a `Response` object to the client when you have already sent a `200` response along with a twig template as the body. What you could do is inject a `meta` redirect tag into the page or use JS:

For example:

```
{% if somecondition %}
<script>window.location.href = {{yourRoute}}</script>
{% endif }
```